Issue with a DC-DC boost converter
I have designed a variable-output boost DC-DC converter (LM5158RTER) to step up 5 V to 40 V. After receiving the PCB, I noticed that the output is fixed at 4.98 V, even when adjusting the potentiometer in the feedback loop. I have attached the schematic for your reference. Could you please review it and let me know if you identify any issues?

One observation I made is that in the reference design, a resistor divider is used to feed the EN/UVLO pin, whereas I have directly connected this pin to VMAIN (5V). Additionally, the reference design includes a capacitor directly connected to GND in parallel with the current circuit (R197, C357) on the COMP pin. In contrast, I used a different configuration. Also, in the reference design, RT is connected directly to GND, while I have used a resistor (R196) in my design. Could you please advise if these differences could be the cause of the issue, or if there are other areas I should investigate?
SW signal:


Can you please check the following pins on your oscilloscope, EN, FB, SS, SW?

Abs max V(FB) is 4V, no current limit specified; are you sure you haven't damaged the part?

"Connect the low-side feedback resistor as close to AGND as possible" Hmm how do you plan to do that?

@winny sure, I will post it as soon as possible

@Lundin would you please explain more what do you mean by this?

@winny I did the measurements, EN=4.98V, FB=1.8V, SS=3.48V, SW=4.98V, I add the scope view of SW also on the the post itself.

@Tim Williams it is around 1.8V, I add more details on the post

Your SW oscillogram is 50 Hz noise. The circuit is not switching. At FB = 1.8 V, you are 80 % above the setpoint, so the regulator is happy. Something is up with your voltage divider. Remove your digipot and replace with a resistor to make sure the base circuit is ok.

@winny thanks, what could be reason do you think? how we can fix it/

Calculation error in the divider, wrong digipot setting, the code to control the digipot? Measure every node in your divider.

That is a 10k digital pot at the low end of the FB divider network. The LM5158 has a Vref of 1.0v. You want a max of 40v.
I'd have considered setting R194 to 200k and putting a 10k resistor between FB and ground in parallel with the digital pot.
In the worst case, say the digital pot output is high impedance, the Vfb is limited to 2.0 volts. The data sheet says this about the FB pin: Connect the low-side feedback resistor as close to AGND as possible.  Disclaimer: I have not used these 2 devices.

@6v6gt yes that was the issue, I replaced the pot with a fixed value resistor, and then the issue is solved.

@ winny thanks, the issue was the pot and I replaced the pot with a fixed value resistor, and then the issue is solved.

The issue was from the potentiometer.  The address of the potentiometer on the I2C bus was not correct in my code. In fact AD0=1, and AD1 are floating in my hardware, which is not a good idea. If I connect AD0=1 and AD1=0, the address will be 1001100, in fact I have a fixed value in my feedback resistor divider.


I made the following adjustment in my schematic:

After making the potentiometer work, the LM5158RTER started switching at 2MHz:

The second issue was that I had a mistake on my BOM. I mistakenly have bought the 50K version of the potentiometer, but I needed to use  the 10K version.

200 MHz? The scope seems to show 2 MHz. And 200 MHz is an absurdly high switching frequency for a switching converter; even 2 MHz is on the high end of the normal range.

@Hearth thanks for the useful comment, it was a typo, I edited the answer now.
